# Calculating length of string that contains Unicode characters

Tags: c#, json, string, unicode, httpresponse

We have been struggling with calculating the length of a string which contains Unicode characters `e.g (Word characters such as ’)` that get pasted into our systems's `text-area's` then get saved. When we need to return that same saved string and we need to calculate our Response `content-length` the normal `c#` string.Length does not calculate the length correctly since Unicode has more than one character.

We have tried using the `System.Globalization.StringInfo` class to read the amount of chars but to no avail as it still comes up short on the correct length of the request. Say for instance the Json response object's last closing curly bracket gets cut off by the browser since the length is too short.

If someone can perhaps shed any light on something that they have used that works it would be greatly appreciated. What we tried so far:

```
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", content.GetType() == typeof(string) ? 
new System.Globalization.StringInfo(content.ToString()).LengthInTextElements.
ToString() : ((byte[])content).Length.ToString());
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you have a C# string or a JSON string or a byte[]? Are you interested in number of characters, number of bytes or number of _printed positions_ i.e. length of line if printed?

Comment: Content-length is in bytes.  So is it even possible to determine the content-length solely from the content?  Won't it vary based on the encoding?  If it goes out as UTF-8 the length would differ from UTF-16.  It could also be gzip'd.  This header is really for the web server to determine.  Or maybe I am confusing content-length with transfer-length.  (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

Comment: I also bellieve that content-length is supposed to be byte-count!

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, The method that we are making the changes to is sort of the Request and response handler that was built that our apps are using, its a central HTTP request handler that based on the requested url will call the appropriate method of an app out of a list of apps and also then send back its response . My response that i am sending back is essentially a Dictionary<string,object> that has been serialized by Newtonsoft.Json library into a json string, and calculating the length of that json string is the problem when it contains Unicode characters, I hope that is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an arbitrary block of bytes, which you know represents some text, and which is encoded using UTF8, the only way to know the actual character count is to decode the text. E.g. by passing it to `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`. Then you just look at the length of the `string` returned.

That said, the `Content-Length` field of an HTTP response is supposed to indicate the length of the response in bytes. If you must set the length yourself, you should just use the total byte count. But if you are using e.g. [`HttpResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Web.HttpResponse(v=vs.110).aspx) I would expect this field to be set automatically on your behalf.

Comment: I agree with you that the HTTP response calculates the length of the response correctly, if i take out the Header for content-length the browser can construct the json object properly without any trouble since the HTTP response does it for you, but our architect for some reason added the header of content-length into the WriteResponse class. I'll keep testing to see if the content-length is worked out correctly for all the other permutations of data, and if it does i'll mark your answer correct and go correct our architect.